# Instagram API search by hashtag

Tags: instagram-api

I want to search recently media by hashtag using the instagram api

```
{
  "pagination": {
    "deprecation_warning": "next_max_id and min_id are deprecated for this endpoint; use min_tag_id and max_tag_id instead"
  },
  "meta": {
    "code": 200
  },
  "data": [

  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered that I can only search for tags within my own media and not publicly available media using this function even though I believe this is supposed to be scoped public_content. (This is probably better off as a comment, but I can't comment yet ... :P)

Comment: It works for me, when you are in standbox mode you can search for tags within user's of your app.

Comment: Ah, yes, only within users of my own app. I discovered that after posting this ... :(